# Convert nested JSON to JSON String on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find a way to sink nested values to Elasticsearch.

The example JSON string looks like this:

```
{ "a": "b", "nestedField": { "b": "bb", "c": { "v": "super nested!" } } }
```

Expectation:

```
key: a
value: b

key: nestedField
value: "{ "b": "bb", "c": { "v": "super nested!" } }"
```

Reality:

```
key: a
value: b

key: nestedField.b
value: bb

key: nestedField.c.v
value: super nested!
```

From what I understand Elasticsearch's library automatically detect nested fields and flattens it. I already searched on the documents but can't find any solution (I hope I just missed that). Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested
you need to make sure  that  the document is mapped to nested datatype

Comment: create the mapping for your index. Example `PUT your_index_name
 {
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "a": { "type":"text"},
         "nestedField":{ "type":"nested"}
      }
   }
 }`